# React onSelect and onDeselect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React JS to detect if an user is selecting an input field. If the user selects the input box, then it triggers the React hook, and then changes the state `inputSelected` from false to true.

The React Hook:

```
const [inputSelected, setInputSelected] = useState(false)
```

The JSX input field:

```
<input type="text" onSelect={e => setInputSelected(true)} />
```

What I want to achieve is when the user is no longer selecting the input field, turn the `inputSelected` state back to false. I am wondering if there is a `onDeselect` type of event for React that I can listen to? Or is there another way that I can achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is onFocus and onBlur.

```
<input 
       type="text" 
       onFocus={ e => setInputSelected(true)} 
       onBlur={e => setInputSelected(false)}
/>
```

Comment: Hi, that worked, but there is another problem. Once the input field is selected, there is a drop menu (a div) appearing. If any items on that drop menu div is clicked, the onBlur  event shouldn't be triggered. Currently, when the drop menu is clicked, the onBlur triggers, and the whole drop menu is hidden because it depends on inputSelected state

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `blur` event:

```
<input type="text" onSelect={e => setInputSelected(true)} onBlur={e => setInputSelected(false)}/>
```

Comment: Hi, that worked, but there is another problem. Once the input field is selected, there is a drop menu (a div) appearing. If any items on that drop menu div is clicked, the `onBlur ` event shouldn't be triggered. Currently, when the drop menu is clicked, the onBlur triggers, and the whole drop menu is hidden because it depends on `inputSelected` state

Comment: Sound more like you should use a select. What kind of menu do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Given your feedback on Marvin and sandrooco's responses, I'd add a conditional to the `onblur` event handler.

Check if one of the menu options has been selected before you call the `setInputSelected(false)` hook.